# Search for the exact string or skip the line that contains a string

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I have a problem that when I search for a string `"code:A1"` it gives also the line that contains `"code:A14"`. I want to search for the exact word `"code:A1"` or just ban `"code:A14"` from the code. Here's what I did and it doesn't work:

```
try
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"<path to file>"))
    {
        string motcletest = "code:A1";
        string motcle = "code:A16";
        string motcledm = "code:A14";
        string line;

        line = file.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            if (line.Contains(motcletest) || line.Contains(motcle))
            {
                SetupV02_textbox.Text = line;
            }
            if (line.Contains(motcledm))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null);

        //string retval = SetupV02_textbox.Text.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First(p => p.Equals(motcle));
        string setup = SetupV02_textbox.Text;
        string testomada2 = setup.Split(new string[] { "code:" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
        label2.Text = testomada2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it proper you should post the content of your text file. 
Anyway you can use the following to ban `code:A14` and select only `code:A16` and `code:A1`

```
if ((linee.Contains(motcletest) || linee.Contains(motcle)) && (!linee.Contains(motcledm)))
{
    SetupV02_textbox.Text = linee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use equals if you want the exact same values and there's no extra content in the line ,

linee.Equals("code:A1")